Passports lost, is it going to impact US visit visa application?
I have lost my passports- the current one as well as the previous expired one, they had no visa stamps on them. I was planning to apply for a US visit visa to see my elderly parents, but now I have to do it using a new passport. How likely is it to influence the outcome, seeing as you have to mention the details of lost or stolen passports in the online application?

Almost certainly no impact - I would expect the purpose of asking you about lost or stolen passports is so that they can find out about your previous visits, not because they are going to blame you for losing them.

@DJClayworth and possibly so they can make a note for border control to be on the lookout for people with those passports. Certainly not the prime purpose, but every little bit helps to keep out people on stolen or fake passports.

Having lost a passport will not impact your visa application.
The reasons they want to know about lost passports are:

Because they want to know about any visits you made on those passports before they were lost;
So they can add them to their list of invalid passports, which will flag them if somebody tries to use them;
So that if you did something illegal or made a visit you didn't want them to know about using them you couldn't later say " That wasn't me, someone used my stolen passport".

